# Why Visual Basic ComboBox Properties not showing ITEMS option to add items?

Tags: excel, combobox, items

In Macro Enabled excel 2007
1. Created UserForm.
2.Added ComboBox from ToolBox.
3.In Properties of Combobox, "Items" option is not available.

Please your suggestions.

Thanks
Ajit Teli

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/161598/how-to-add-data-to-a-combobox-control-or-a-listbox-control-in-excel-or

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the items inside `UserForm_Initialize()`, using `.AddItem` method or `.List` property.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    'The list is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    ComboBox1.AddItem "A", 2
    'The list is now 1, 2, A, 3, 4, 5
End Sub
```

You can also assign a 2-D array to a combobox. Only the first column will be shown in the combobox, while other values are invisible but readable and editable.